# R/Shiny: dirname not accepting reactive value

Tags: r, shiny

Trying to pass a reactive value into the dirname() function in R/Shiny.
Getting error:
Error in dirname: a character vector argument expected

I setup reactiveValues like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    v = reactiveValues(root = '/path', files = NULL, folders = NULL)
```

I then have a button press observeEvent:

```
observeEvent(input$Btn, {
    v$files <<- grep("stuff", list.files(path = files.path(v$root), recursive=T, pattern=".py"))
    v$folders <<- dirname(v$files)
})
```

Why won't dirname accept the reactive value "v$files" as an argument? and how can I get it so it does accept it?

Comment: it seems you're missing the `value = TRUE` argument to `grep`. (And why the double arrow assignment? it doesn't seem necessary)

Comment: @Aurèle wow, can't believe i missed that....fixing the grep arguments got it to work as intended.  The double arrow assignment was from a previous config where reactive values weren't used, and the values had to be assigned globally.  I guess using reactive values this is not needed, learned something new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Aurèle, The missing value=T argument in the grep was causing the issue.  Adding that gave me the intended result.

```
grep("stuff", list.files(path = files.path(v$root), recursive=T, pattern=".py"), invert=T, value=T)
```

Also pointed out by Aurèle, I switched the assignments to single arrow since double is not necessary when using reactive values it seems.